# Cannot run unit tests in scala intelliJ

Tags: scala

I was trying to run scala unit tests and I ran into this issue.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V

at org.scalatest.time.Units.<init>(Units.scala:33)
at org.scalatest.time.Days$.<init>(Units.scala:293)
at org.scalatest.time.Days$.<clinit>(Units.scala)
at org.scalatest.time.Span$.<init>(Span.scala:584)
at org.scalatest.time.Span$.<clinit>(Span.scala)
at org.scalatest.Suite$.<init>(Suite.scala:1399)
at org.scalatest.Suite$.<clinit>(Suite.scala)
at org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner.<init>(JUnitRunner.scala:61)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at
```

The code compiles fine. Just the tests do not run. I already set up the global sdk and libraries. Please help.

Comment: Did you try building the project manually?

Comment: @Feyyaz. Yea. The thing builds fine. Its running any of the tests that just fails.

Comment: No idea then. Everytime I have this kind of error, CMD+F9 (Mac) solves the issue for me.

Comment: @ArunavSanyal same issue here. did you manage to figure out?

Comment: @salient, na. I am just rerunning the test targets right now in command line. It sucks.